# Surefire reports doesn't generate report

Tags: maven, testing, junit, report, surefire

My doubt it's simple, when I'm executing JUnit test's directly from eclipse, surefire report isn't gerenated, even the folders (target/surefire/surefire-report) aren't generated but when I'm executing from cmd(mvn test) all reports or prints are generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you use "run as -> Junit Test", which only runs the Junit testt themselves, without using surefire. If you rightclick on the project and choose "run as -> maven test" it would have the same effect as running `mvn test` from the commandline, i.e. your result (not reports) would be generated.

Comment: It works in parts. Before this problem I was running in JUnit test and it's generated, but now isn't. When I runned with maven test, ok, folders are generated but the printscreen isn't

Comment: By printscreen you mean the generated html page? This is created by the surefire reports plugin which would need to be bound to a phase in order to generate anything. Show us your pom please.